# Употребляется ли в современном языке "в моей воле"?

Tags: выбор-слов, архаизмы

...в значении: в моей власти, в моих силах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня: того-сего я ещё не знаю, не умею, зато...

> Зато я знаю, что в моей воле к этому стремиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка:
[**в воле**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/1416/%D0%92_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5), *чьей*. Зависит только от чьих-либо возможностей, желаний.
*Теперь я знаю, в вашей воле Меня презреньем наказать* (Пушкин).

В словарной статье пометки *арх.* или *устар.* отсутствуют.
В современной литературе встречается, действительно, редко, но "кое-что" нашлось.

*— Я ничего такого не хотела сказать, — пролепетала Варя. — Вы, барыня, не думайте, что я чего-то подозреваю или… **Все в вашей воле**. Хотите, казните меня, хотите — милуйте.

Елена Павловна быстро пошла вперед и бросила на ходу:

— Ни казнить, ни миловать я тебя не собираюсь. А вот то, что **все в моей воле**, — тут ты права.*
А. Князева. Тайна рождения

*— **В вашей воле** наказать меня за дерзость, но я всегда верила, что наш король мудрый и справедливый правитель* (Н. Любимка. Страж огня. Академия сиятельных).

Мне кажется, что сегодня вполне возможно использование этого словосочетания, — оно всем понятно, и ощущения книжности или архаичности не вызывает (во всяком случае, у меня).

Answer (score 1):

Употребляется ли в современном языке в моей воле в значении: в моей власти, в моих силах?

Если судить по Нацкорпусу, то оно употреблялось раньше, сейчас чаще используется слово ***волен***.

Дальше меня выставляют за дверь, и я **волен** делать, что захочу. [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]

Я **волен**, кажется, сам распорядиться своей судьбой… [Л. Р. Кабо. Ровесники Октября (1964)]